# What maps should be baked in a high poly model to use in low poly?

Tags: texturing

Which of the following maps should I draw in High Poly, bake and transfer to Low Poly, and which ones should I draw directly on Low Poly?

When modeling a human character. Roughness map, Ambient Occlusion map, Diffuse map, Displacement map.

Answer (score 1):

There's no right or wrong answer for that, it depends on what you need.
Usually to transfer model details from high poly to low poly you'll need to bake the normal map and/or displacement ("height") map. If all you're trying to bake is the geometry detail, that's all you need.

If you already textured the high poly model, you'll want to bake the diffuse to transfer the color map to the low poly. If your high poly already has roughness maps you'll want to bake them too, and the same goes for metallic, specular, etcetera.
Ambient Occlusion map I think is necessary only for game assets (and even so, not always necessary). As I said, everything depends on what your needs are.